# Page doesn't check for PHP Session

Tags: php, html, mysql

so I currently have a table page which I wanted to protect so I have a login session and session pages setup to handle that but currently when I go to my table.php page it just loops me back to index.php(where the login is handled)

**index.php**

```
    <?php
###########################################################
/*
This software belongs to DSKC.TK using it without the explicit
permission of the owner is strictly prohibited
No modifications should be made to this file without a permission from
the creator of this file
Please contact DSKC.TK for further instructions.
*/
###########################################################
session_name('LoginForm');
@session_start();

error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");


 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE email = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         session_register("myusername");
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: table.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Login Form</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<!-- Stuff ends here-->
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
    $error = '';
    if(isset($_POST['is_login'])){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." WHERE `email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' AND `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
        $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
        if(!empty($user)){
            $_SESSION['user_info'] = $user;
        }
        else{
            $error = 'Wrong email or password.';
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['ac']) && $_GET['ac'] == 'logout'){
        $_SESSION['user_info'] = null;
        unset($_SESSION['user_info']);
    }

?>




    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_info']) && is_array($_SESSION['user_info'])) { ?>
        <form id="login-form" name="form1"> <!-- paste here -->

            <div id="form-content">
                <div class="welcome">
                    <?php echo $_SESSION['user_info']['name']  ?>, you are logged in. 
<p> Go here <a href="http://dd.22web.org/Test/table.php"> click me </a>
                    <br /><br />


                    <?php echo $_SESSION['user_info']['content']  ?>
                    <br /><br />


                    <a href="index.php?ac=logout" style="color:#3ec038">Logout</a>
                </div>  
            </div>

        </form>


<?php } else { ?>
        <form id="login-form" class="login-form" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="is_login" value="1">
            <div class="h1">Login Form</div>
            <div id="form-content">
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <div><input id="email" name="email" class="form-control required" type="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
                </div>
               <div class="group">
                    <label for="name">Password</label>
                    <div><input id="password" name="password" class="form-control required" type="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
                </div>
                <?php if($error) { ?>
                    <em>
                        <label class="err" for="password" generated="true" style="display: block;"><?php echo $error ?></label>
                    </em>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="group submit">
                    <label class="empty"></label>
                    <div><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="form-loading" class="hide"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>
        </form>
    <?php } ?>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Thats the index.php where I handle all the login stuff, config.php is as below:

```
    <?php
###########################################################
/*
This software belongs to DSKC.TK modifying or usage of this file is strictly
prohibited without an explicit permission from the creator.
*/
###########################################################

/* Define MySQL connection details and database table name */ 
$SETTINGS["hostname"] = '';
$SETTINGS["mysql_user"] = '';
$SETTINGS["mysql_pass"] = '';
$SETTINGS["mysql_database"] = '';
$SETTINGS["USERS"] = 'php_users_login'; // this is the default table name that we used

/* Connect to MySQL */
$connection = mysql_connect($SETTINGS["hostname"], $SETTINGS["mysql_user"], $SETTINGS["mysql_pass"]) or die ('Unable to connect to MySQL server.<br ><br >Please make sure your MySQL login details are correct.');
$db = mysql_select_db($SETTINGS["mysql_database"], $connection) or die ('request "Unable to select database."');
?>
```

Then I have the table.php page which I want users to be prompted at if they aren't logged in:

```
    <?php
###########################################################
/*
This software belongs to DSKC.TK using it without the explicit
permission of the owner is strictly prohibited
No modifications should be made to this file without a permission from
the creator of this file
Please contact DSKC.TK for further instructions.
*/
###########################################################
include('session.php');






?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Table</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

</head>

<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Thats the table page which I want to be protected if the user isn't logged in, but currently for some reason it just redirects me back to login.php even if i am logged in, finally I have the code for session.php page:

```
 <?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username from admin where username = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['email'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location: index.php");
   }
?>
```

I understand this is a lot of code to go through so I would like to thank everyone in advance, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Remove `session_register("myusername");`. It was deprecated as of PHP 5.3 & removed in 5.4. Your session might is also not br working because your `include('config.php');` is before your `session_start();`. Turn on error reporting at the top of that page and let us know what it returns (`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`). Not to mention, you're suppressing errors (`@`), don't do that, instead, handle the errors properly. Also, SQL Injection will get you here. `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't protect you ([*Source*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5741264/2518525)).

Comment: hey there so I removed session_register("myusername") and also included session start before include(); but it still does the same thing and sorry but I don't know how and where I can turn on the error reporting part could you please elaborate.

Comment: Put it on your `session.php` file

Comment: so I added that in and it just redirects me back to login page(index.php) and doesnt show me any error